# Rails 4 - Respond only to JSON and not HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build an API in rails 4, and am having an issue where rails returns a 500 error instead of a 406 when using `respond_to :json` and trying to access the html version.

Here's an example controller demonstrating the problem:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

I also have a jbuilder view for `index` that works when accessing via JSON. If I try accessing the route without the JSON extension, It attempts to load the HTML template (which doesn't exist) and returns a 500 error, instead of just rendering JSON or returning a 406 error.

What could be causing this? Cheers for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579774/respond-to-only-json-in-rails?rq=1

Comment: I did see that, but I want to know why it doesn't work with just the `respond_to :json` setting

Comment: `respond_to :json` and `respond_with @posts` properly respond with *HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable* to me in Production. In Development you get a "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error" and an `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Comment: Sorry I tried to answer but my post was deleted by a moderator since I also answered the other "possible duplicate" even though this one is more clearly Rails 4. So here you go... In Rails 4, you have to pass a lambda in the route to enforce a constraint like so: 
`resources :posts, constraints: lambda { |req| req.format == :json }`

Comment: You can see more in the second note in the Rails guide here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

Comment: @TomBrunoli please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227145/get-content-type-of-request/63579270#63579270

Answer (score 48):

I believe there are 2 parts here:
1) json only **requests** in rails
2) json only **responses** in rails

1)  Configure your application controller to ensure ***json requests*** only

```
# app/controller/application_controller.rb  
before_action :ensure_json_request  

def ensure_json_request  
  return if request.format == :json
  render :nothing => true, :status => 406  
end
```

2)  Configure your Rails API routes to ensure ***json responses*** only

```
# config/routes.rb  
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do  
  namespace :api, constraints: { format: 'json' } do  
    namespace :v1 do  
      resources :posts  
    end  
  end  
end
```

Comment: Instead of `params[:format] == "json" || request.headers["Accept"] =~ /json/` you can use `request.format.symbol == :json`.

Comment: Nice call. Updated with `request.format == :json` as `symbol` is not required per this other [request format question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227145/get-content-type-of-request#answer-33768811)

Comment: Rather than `render :nothing => true, :status => 406` you can use `head :not_acceptable`

Answer (score 42):

To avoid loading the non-existent HTML template, set the default resource type as JSON in config/routes.rb:

```
resources :posts, :defaults => { :format => :json }
```

Comment: This does not provide a constraint, which is implied by the question. The idea would be that if .json format was not specified, rails would not match on the routes and continue on down the hierarchy.

Answer (score 22):

In Rails 4, you need to pass a lambda to enforce the constraint on a route.

Unfortunately, this will NOT work because it will still try to serve up (or attempt to serve up) an html template since the format is an optional parameter:

```
resources :posts, constraints: { format: 'json' }
```

This DOES work (uses the lambda):

```
resources :posts, constraints: lambda { |req| req.format == :json }
```

See the second (final) note in [this section of the Rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `scope`, however `defaults: { format: 'json' }` does work.

Answer (score 5):

As you are using a before_filter, you will have a 406 Not Acceptable if a request for a format is made which is not defined.

Example:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json


  def show
    @record = Record.find params[:id]

    respond_with @record
  end
end
```

The other way would be to add a before_filter to check for the format and react accordingly.

Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_format


  def check_format
    render :nothing => true, :status => 406 unless params[:format] == 'json'
  end
end
```

But i think, you can just do it:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @posts }
end
```

Further informations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: The problem I have with this is that the `respond_to :json` still lets html responses go through. I want all responses to be JSON, regardless of the requested format.

Comment: Did you create your json on the view?

Comment: `params[:format] == 'json'` is not enough. When request is made with `Accept: application/json` header, params[:format] is empty, but Rails still responds with JSON.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this, as I was also facing this issue and now it is solved by using this solution.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    render json: @posts
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

`constraints` was not working for POST requests and then I tried `defaults` it works for all.

```
namespace :api, :defaults => { :format => 'json' } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users do
        collection do
          get 'profile'
        end
      end
      post 'signup' => 'users#create'
      post 'login' => 'user_sessions#create'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by having a before filter that sets the request to JSON explicitly.

`request.format = :json`

Answer (score 0):

when you try a responses in json is beacuse you only need some properties i used this

```
@my_model=Model.select(:attributeN, :attributeN......, attributeN)
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render json: @my_model
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try `gem 'active_model_serializers'`. Its really awesome and keeps clean.

**ApplicationController:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format != 'application/json' }
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
end
```

**Routes:**

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resource :posts
end
```

**Posts Controller:**

```
def index
   render json: Post.all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this but regarding your comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21982690/1979736):

> I want all responses to be JSON

The easiest solution would be:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.all { render :json => @posts }
end
```