# Heroku routes with subdomain constraint crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have this code in my `routes.rb`, which works well on my local machine. However, when deployed to Heroku it crashes the server and the routes don't load any page.

```
class NoSubdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    !request.subdomain.present?
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  constraints(NoSubdomain) do
    # Routes without subdomain
  end

  constraints lambda { |req| req.format == :json && req.subdomain == 'api' } do
    namespace :crew do
      scope module: :api do # For API folder to organise files
        namespace :v1 do
          # Routes with subdomain
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I get this to work?

Here are the error logs:

```
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236210+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236211+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236212+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236213+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236213+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236214+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/lograge-0.4.1/lib/lograge/rails_ext/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call_app'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236216+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236216+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236217+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236219+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236220+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236221+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/quiet_assets-1.1.0/lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236222+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236224+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236224+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236226+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236244+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236245+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236262+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236263+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236265+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236267+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236285+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236286+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236286+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236289+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:24:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236290+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236292+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:171:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236312+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236313+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236313+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236334+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.17.1.326/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236335+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236336+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:152:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236337+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236337+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
2017-04-11T02:41:59.236338+00:00 app[web.1]: App 136 stdout:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

**Update**

Here is more info about the routes (not the entire file, which has 500 lines)

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

class NoSubdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    !request.subdomain.present?
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  constraints(NoSubdomain) do
    devise_for :users, controllers: {invitations: 'admin/invitations', registrations: 'users/registrations', passwords: 'users/passwords'}
    resources :users

    devise_scope :user do

      authenticated :user do

        # Admin dashboard
        namespace :admin do
          resources :keywords
        end

        namespace :customer do
          get 'dashboard', to: 'dashboard#main'
        end

        namespace :crew do
          get 'schedule', to: 'schedule#index'
        end

        # Role based redirect - # PassthroughController
        root to: 'passthrough#index'
      end

      unauthenticated :user do
        # redirects if not logged in
        match '/admin(/*path)' => 'devise/sessions#new', via: :get
        match '/crew(/*path)' => 'devise/sessions#new', via: :get
        match '/customer(/*path)' => 'devise/sessions#new', via: :get
      end

    end

    namespace :shared, path: '/' do
      get 'ajax_update_page', to: 'ajax_quote#update_page'
    end

    namespace :public do
      get 'invitations/accept/:invitation_token', to: 'invitations#edit', as: 'invitations_edit'
      patch 'invitations/accept/:invitation_token', to: 'invitations#update', as: 'invitations_update'
    end

    namespace :shared, path:'/' do
      get 'find_availabilities', to: 'availabilities#find_availabilities'
      get 'find_available_dates', to: 'availabilities#find_available_dates'
      resources :attachments
    end

    namespace :public, path: 'booking_steps' do
      # get 'ideal_booking_time', to: 'booking_steps#ideal_booking_time'
      patch 'update_mixpanel_alias_created', to: 'booking_steps#update_mixpanel_alias_created'
      resources :booking_steps, only: [:index, :show, :update], path: ''
    end

    namespace :api do
      get 'crew_birthdays', to: 'crew_birthdays#index'
    end

    root to: 'public/pages#index', as: 'landing'
  end



  # For Rails 4, lambda needs to be used to restrict the format of the request
  # http://stackoverflow.com/a/37603236/1076279
  constraints lambda { |req| req.format == :json && req.subdomain == 'api' } do
    namespace :crew do
      scope module: :api do
        namespace :v1 do
          namespace :jobs do
            resources :jobs, only: :show
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you are trying to implement an API into your Rails project in which case you should nest the endpoints in a separate controller. Something like this: https://labs.kollegorna.se/blog/2015/04/build-an-api-now/

Comment: try to put `root` in below, outside of `constraints`.

Comment: @7urkm3n If I put the `root` outside the `/` page loads but everything else crashes. I think the problem is with that `NoSubdomain` constraint. @Alexander Luna I'm using the `NoSubdomain` constraint because some routes under the api namespace (I've added more code to the question) have similar routes so I need to distinguish subdomain vs no subdomain.

Comment: @migu Could you post yr whole routes ?

Comment: @7urkm3n I've added more info to the bottom of the question (not all routes though, that's 500 lines of code). Strange thing is that it works perfectly fine on my local machine.