# i have to put a parameter in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So im trying to do json calls on my rails app, and i want to use a parameter in my namespace route. in routes.rb i have this :

```
namespace :api do 
 resources :forescast do
 end
end
```

that gives my route 127.0.0.1:3000/api/forecast.json that works but
what i want is to put a parameter after forecast,not after .json, tha i want to use in my controller as a param something like:

> 127.0.0.1:3000/api/forecast/[service_name].json

i know i have to put it in routes.rb but i dont know how to make it. The outcome would be a json with data of that specific service, not all of them. I know i could make it as param at the final of the route. But im looking for a way to get it in that position of the route and use it as a param in my controller.

There is an exemple of how i would like it to be:
[image]
:location begin a param to use in my controller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails 4 - Respond only to JSON and not HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978580/rails-4-respond-only-to-json-and-not-html)

Comment: @nuaky So what im trying to get is my model location has a service that is FK from another model, i want to use that service name as param but before .json like api/forecast/[servicename].json?(extra params if neded). Not sure if im explaining correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this on `routes.rb`
`get 'api/forecast/service_name:' , to:  'api/forecasts#index'`